# Java: JTree with plus/minus icons for expansion and collapse?

Tags: java, swing, jtree

How do I make my Jtree look like something below, with plus and minus icons that allows expansion and collapse?

Currently, the default JTree only expands and collapses when you double click. I want to override this double click for another functionality and let the user expand/collapse the tree by only clicking on the minus and plus icons such as below.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> with plus and minus icons that allows expansion and collapse?

These are the default icons for the Windows LAF. Other LAF's have different icons.

You can set your own icons by using the UIManager. See [UIManager Defaults](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/).

Or you can use custom icons for a single JTree only. See [Customizing a Tree's Display](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#display).

> let the user expand/collapse the tree by only clicking on the minus and plus icons such as below.

This is the default behaviour.

Comment: But how do you override the double-click behavior to do something else instead of expanding the row?  The expansion should happen only when you click on the +/- arrows; a double-click anywhere else on the row should do something different (such as open the selected item in some other view).

Comment: I can't figure out how to stop the double click from collapsing/expanding and at the same time allow collapsing/expansion when the +/- are clicked.

Answer (score 12):

You have to change the `Tree.collapsedIcon` and `Tree.expandedIcon` properties of the L&F and supply your own icons:

```
UIManager.put("Tree.collapsedIcon", new IconUIResource(new NodeIcon('+')));
UIManager.put("Tree.expandedIcon",  new IconUIResource(new NodeIcon('-')));
```

Here is the icon I use, it's simple square with a +/- inside:

```
public class NodeIcon implements Icon {

    private static final int SIZE = 9;

    private char type;

    public NodeIcon(char type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
        g.setColor(UIManager.getColor("Tree.background"));
        g.fillRect(x, y, SIZE - 1, SIZE - 1);

        g.setColor(UIManager.getColor("Tree.hash").darker());
        g.drawRect(x, y, SIZE - 1, SIZE - 1);

        g.setColor(UIManager.getColor("Tree.foreground"));
        g.drawLine(x + 2, y + SIZE / 2, x + SIZE - 3, y + SIZE / 2);
        if (type == '+') {
            g.drawLine(x + SIZE / 2, y + 2, x + SIZE / 2, y + SIZE - 3);
        }
    }

    public int getIconWidth() {
        return SIZE;
    }

    public int getIconHeight() {
        return SIZE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or simply think :)

```
class SourceListTreeUI extends BasicTreeUI
{

    int offset = 10;

    protected int getRowX(int row, int depth)
    {
        return totalChildIndent * (depth + offset);
    }
}
```