# fireTableDataChanged() after a ListSelectionEvent causes StackOverFlow

Tags: java, swing, stack-overflow, jtree, listselectionlistener

Essentially what I need to do is set a `ListSelectionListener` on my `JTable` for the row and column model so I know which cell has been clicked, I'm fine this.

If the cell that I've clicked happens to have a `JTree` as it's renderer component then I am to expand/collapse the JTree, adjust the height of the table row and redraw the table. So my `ListSelectionListener` looks like this

```
  static class TableCellSelectionListener implements ListSelectionListener {

    private JTable _t;

    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent lse) {
      if(!lse.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
        int rowSelected = _t.getSelectedRow();
        int colSelected = _t.getSelectedColumn();    
        if(rowSelected > -1 && colSelected > -1) {
          TableCellRenderer renderer = _t.getCellRenderer(rowSelected, colSelected);
          Object obj = _t.getValueAt(rowSelected, colSelected);
          Component c = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(_t, obj, true, false, rowSelected, colSelected);    
          if(c instanceof JTree) {
            JTree tree = (JTree) c;
            TreePath path = tree.getPathForRow(0);

            if(tree.isExpanded(path)) {
              tree.collapsePath(path);
              tree.fireTreeCollapsed(path);
            } else {
              tree.expandPath(path);
              tree.fireTreeExpanded(path);
            }          

            Enumeration<TableColumn> columns = _t.getColumnModel().getColumns();
            while(columns.hasMoreElements()) {
              TableColumn col = columns.nextElement();
              int colIndex = col.getModelIndex();
              if(_t.getColumnClass(colIndex) == JTree.class && colIndex != colSelected) {
                JTree t = (JTree) _t.getValueAt(rowSelected, colIndex);
                TreePath p = t.getPathForRow(0);
                if(tree.isExpanded(path) && !t.isExpanded(p)) {
                  t.expandPath(p);
                  t.fireTreeExpanded(p);
                } else if(!tree.isExpanded(path) && t.isExpanded(p)) {
                  t.collapsePath(p);
                  t.fireTreeCollapsed(p);
                }
              }
            }          

            _t.setRowHeight(rowSelected, c.getPreferredSize().height);
            //Line below causes StackOverFlow
            ((SortableTableModel)_t.getModel()).fireTableDataChanged();
            _t.clearSelection();
          }
        }
      }    
    }

    public void setTable(JTable t) {
      _t = t;
    }

  }
```

What would be the "correct" approach for doing this?

Because I genuinely am interested in the correct approach here's the full compilable code, run it you'll soon see my goal (as already mentioned table cells with JTree components to expand/collapse, the height of the table row also needs to reflect the JTree state)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.plaf.IconUIResource;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;

public class ProgressBarPCSTable {

  private ProgressBarValueTracker pbValueTracker = new ProgressBarValueTracker();

  private String[] columnNames = {"JobID","Progress", "Status"};  
  private DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(null, columnNames) {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
      return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
      return false;
    }
  };

  private JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);

  public JComponent makeUI() {
    TableColumn progressColumn = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
    progressColumn.setCellRenderer(new JTreeRenderer(true, pbValueTracker));
    TableColumn statusColumn = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2);
    statusColumn.setCellRenderer(new JTreeRenderer(false, pbValueTracker));

    //Setup row/column selection listeners
    table.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
    TableCellSelectionListener cellSelectionListener = new TableCellSelectionListener(table);
    table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(cellSelectionListener);
    table.getColumnModel().getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(cellSelectionListener);

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
        startTask(new Object[][]{{"000001"}, {0}, {"complete"}});
        startTask(new Object[][]{{"000002"}, {0,0}, {"processing","rendering pdf"}});
        startTask(new Object[][]{{"000003"}, {0,0,0}, {"processing","rendering pdf","rendering afp"}});
        startTask(new Object[][]{{"000004"}, {0,0,0,0}, {"processing","rendering pdf","rendering afp","rendering postscript"}});
        startTask(new Object[][]{{"000005"}, {0,0,0,0,0}, {"processing","normalsing","enhancing","sorting","rendering"}});
      }
    });
    JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    p.add(new JScrollPane(table));
    return p;
  }

  private void startTask(final Object[][] job) {
    final int key = tableModel.getRowCount();
    final String jobID = (String) job[0][0];    

    final DefaultMutableTreeNode progressRoot = new DefaultMutableTreeNode((Integer)job[1][0]);
    final DefaultMutableTreeNode statusRoot = new DefaultMutableTreeNode((String)job[2][0]);

    final DefaultTreeModel progressTreeModel = new DefaultTreeModel(progressRoot);
    final DefaultTreeModel statusTreeModel = new DefaultTreeModel(statusRoot);

    final JTree progressTree = new JTree(progressTreeModel);
    final JTree statusTree = new JTree(statusTreeModel);

    if(job[1].length > 1) {
      initJTree(progressRoot, Arrays.copyOfRange(job[1], 1, job[1].length, Integer[].class));
      ((DefaultTreeModel)progressTree.getModel()).nodeChanged(progressRoot);
    }

    if(job[2].length > 1) {
      initJTree(statusRoot, Arrays.copyOfRange(job[2], 1, job[2].length, String[].class)); 
    }

    pbValueTracker.initPVMap(progressTree);

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
        startProgressBarTask(progressTree, progressRoot, key, false);
        int childCount = progressRoot.getChildCount();        
        for(int i=0; i < childCount; i++) {
          startProgressBarTask(progressTree, (DefaultMutableTreeNode)progressRoot.getChildAt(i), key, i == 1 ? true : false);          
        }
      }
    });

    tableModel.addRow(new Object[]{jobID, progressTree, statusTree});


  }

  private <T> void initJTree(DefaultMutableTreeNode root, T[] list) {
    for(T t: list) {
      root.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(t));
    }
  }

  private void startProgressBarTask(final JTree progressTree, final DefaultMutableTreeNode node, 
      final int rowCount, final boolean error) {
    LoudCall<Void, JTree> progressShout = new LoudCall<Void, JTree>() {

      @Override
      public Void call() throws Exception {

        SwingWorker<Integer, Integer> progressWorker = new SwingWorker<Integer, Integer>() {

          private int sleepDummy = new Random().nextInt(100) + 1;
          private int lengthOfTask = 120;

          /**
           * Overrides the SwingWorker doInBackground, this version, increments 
           * the value of the % complete and publishes it, the process method will
           * pick up the published value so that the ProgressBarRenderer can
           * deal with it. It also triggers a nodeChanged event on the DefaultTreeModel
           * so that the JTree updates
           */
          @Override
          protected Integer doInBackground() throws Exception {            
            int current = 0;
            DefaultMutableTreeNode root = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) progressTree.getModel().getRoot();
            String suffix = root == node ? "_root" : "_" +root.getIndex(node);
            String key = String.valueOf(System.identityHashCode(progressTree)) +suffix; 
            while(current < lengthOfTask && !isCancelled()) {
              if(error && current >= 60) { //Error test
                cancel(true);
                publish(-1);
                pbValueTracker.putErrMap(key, -1);
                System.out.println(pbValueTracker.getErrMap());
                return -1;
              }
              current++;
              try {
                Thread.sleep(sleepDummy);
              } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                break;
              }
              int value = 100 * current / lengthOfTask;
              publish(value);
              if(!pbValueTracker.getErrMap().containsKey(key)) {
                pbValueTracker.putPVMap(key, value);
              }              
            }
            return sleepDummy * lengthOfTask;
          }

          /**
           * Attach a user object to the node, in this case
           * it is an Integer with the latest value triggered by publish
           * process will fire getTreeCellRendererComponent of the
           * ProgressBarRenderer
           * 
           * @param c - a list of Integer to process, only process the last value set
           */
          @Override
          protected void process(List<Integer> c) {
            node.setUserObject(c.get(c.size() - 1));
            shoutOut(progressTree);            
            ((DefaultTreeModel)progressTree.getModel()).nodeChanged(node);
          }

          @Override
          protected void done() {
            int i = -1;
            if(!isCancelled()) {
              try {
                i = get();
              } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }          
            }
            System.out.println("Value: " +i);
            shoutOut(progressTree);
            ((DefaultTreeModel)progressTree.getModel()).nodeChanged(node);
            System.out.println(pbValueTracker.getPVMap());
          }

        };

        progressWorker.execute();

        return null;
      }

    };

    (new ListenerTask<Void, JTree>(progressShout) {

      @Override
      protected void process(List<JTree> chunks) {
        tableModel.setValueAt(chunks.get(chunks.size() - 1), rowCount, 1);
        tableModel.fireTableDataChanged();
      }      

    }).execute();
  }

  public static void main(String... args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
        createAndShowGUI();
      }
    });
  }

  public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(new ProgressBarPCSTable().makeUI());
    frame.setSize(669, 307);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

}

/**
 * This class listens for selection of a table cell
 * if selected and the cells component is a JTree it
 * expands/collapses the JTree and adjusts the height
 * of the table row accordingly
 * 
 * @author pstatham
 *
 */
class TableCellSelectionListener implements ListSelectionListener {

  private JTable _t;

  public TableCellSelectionListener(JTable t) {
    _t = t;
  }

  @Override
  public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent lse) {
    if(!lse.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
      int rowSelected = _t.getSelectedRow();
      int colSelected = _t.getSelectedColumn();    
      if(rowSelected > -1 && colSelected > -1) {
        TableCellRenderer renderer = _t.getCellRenderer(rowSelected, colSelected);
        Object obj = _t.getValueAt(rowSelected, colSelected);
        Component c = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(_t, obj, true, false, rowSelected, colSelected);    
        if(c instanceof JTree) {
          JTree tree = (JTree) c;
          TreePath path = tree.getPathForRow(0);

          if(tree.isExpanded(path)) {
            tree.collapsePath(path);
            tree.fireTreeCollapsed(path);
          } else {
            tree.expandPath(path);
            tree.fireTreeExpanded(path);
          }          

          Enumeration<TableColumn> columns = _t.getColumnModel().getColumns();
          while(columns.hasMoreElements()) {
            TableColumn col = columns.nextElement();
            int colIndex = col.getModelIndex();
            if(_t.getColumnClass(colIndex) == JTree.class && colIndex != colSelected) {
              JTree t = (JTree) _t.getValueAt(rowSelected, colIndex);
              TreePath p = t.getPathForRow(0);
              if(tree.isExpanded(path) && !t.isExpanded(p)) {
                t.expandPath(p);
                t.fireTreeExpanded(p);
              } else if(!tree.isExpanded(path) && t.isExpanded(p)) {
                t.collapsePath(p);
                t.fireTreeCollapsed(p);
              }
            }
          }          

          _t.setRowHeight(rowSelected, c.getPreferredSize().height);
          ((DefaultTableModel)_t.getModel()).fireTableDataChanged();
          _t.clearSelection();
        }
      }
    }    
  }

}

/**
 * This class keeps track of a particular JProgressBar's previous
 * value in case it has gone in to error
 * @author pstatham
 *
 */
class ProgressBarValueTracker {

  private HashMap<String, Integer> pvMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
  private HashMap<String, Integer> errMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

  public void initPVMap(JTree tree) {
    String key = String.valueOf(System.identityHashCode(tree)) +"_root";
    DefaultMutableTreeNode root = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) ((DefaultTreeModel)tree.getModel()).getRoot();
    pvMap.put(key, (Integer) root.getUserObject());
    for(int i=0; i < root.getChildCount(); i++) {
      key = String.valueOf(System.identityHashCode(tree)) +"_" + i;
      DefaultMutableTreeNode child = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) root.getChildAt(i);
      pvMap.put(key, (Integer) child.getUserObject());
    }
  }

  public void putPVMap(String key, Integer value) {
    pvMap.put(key, value);
  }

  public void putErrMap(String key, Integer value) {
    errMap.put(key, value);
  }

  public HashMap<String, Integer> getPVMap() {
    return pvMap;
  }

  public HashMap<String, Integer> getErrMap() {
    return errMap;
  }

}


/**
 * This class extends the DefaultTreeCellRenderer and returns a JPanel with a
 * JProgressBar attached as its renderer component
 * @author pstatham
 *
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class ProgressBarRenderer extends DefaultTreeCellRenderer {

  private final JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar(0, 100);

  private ProgressBarValueTracker pbValueTracker;

  public ProgressBarRenderer(ProgressBarValueTracker tracker) {
    super();    
    pbValueTracker = tracker;
    setOpaque(true);
    configureProgressBar(progressBar);    
    progressBar.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);    
  }

  @Override
  public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, final Object value, boolean selected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {
    if(((DefaultMutableTreeNode) value).getUserObject() instanceof String) {
      super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value, selected, expanded, leaf, row, hasFocus);
      return this;
    }

    DefaultMutableTreeNode root = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) tree.getModel().getRoot();
    String suffix = root == value ? "_root" : "_" +root.getIndex((DefaultMutableTreeNode)value);
    String key = String.valueOf(System.identityHashCode(tree)) +suffix;    

    JPanel p = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 0));
    p.setBackground(Color.WHITE);    

    JLabel l = (JLabel)super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, null, selected, expanded, leaf, row, hasFocus);

    if(((DefaultMutableTreeNode)value).isRoot() && ((DefaultMutableTreeNode)value).getChildCount() > 0) {
      TreePath path = tree.getPathForRow(row);
      if(tree.isExpanded(path)) {
        l.setIcon(new IconUIResource(new NodeIcon('-')));
      } else {
        l.setIcon(new IconUIResource(new NodeIcon('+')));
      }
    } else {
      l.setIcon(new IconUIResource(new NodeIcon(' ')));
    }

    p.add(l);    

    Integer i = (Integer) ((DefaultMutableTreeNode) value).getUserObject();

    //
    // If Job is in error return a different
    // JProgressBar with a red background
    //
    if(i<0) {            
      JProgressBar errorProgressBar = new JProgressBar(0, 100);
      configureProgressBar(errorProgressBar);
      errorProgressBar.setBackground(Color.RED);      
      errorProgressBar.setValue(pbValueTracker.getPVMap().get(key));
      p.add(errorProgressBar);
    } else {
      progressBar.setValue(i);
      p.add(progressBar);
    }    
    return p;    
  }

  /**
   * Configure a JProgressBar with common options
   * 
   * @param pb JProgressBar to configure
   */
  private void configureProgressBar(JProgressBar pb) {
    pb.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1));
    pb.setForeground(Color.GREEN.darker());
    pb.setStringPainted(true);
    pb.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(pb.getPreferredSize().width, 16));
  }

}

/**
 * This class extends the DefaultTableCellRenderer and returns a JTree
 * as its renderer component. The JTrees renderer
 * can either be an instance of a ProgressBarRenderer or a 
 * DefaultTreeCellRenderer that returns a label with an open/close icon
 * as its renderer component.
 * @author pstatham
 *
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class JTreeRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

  private JTree tree;
  private TreeCellRenderer renderer;  

  public JTreeRenderer(boolean progressTree, ProgressBarValueTracker tracker) {    
    if(progressTree) {
      renderer = new ProgressBarRenderer(tracker);      
    } else {
      renderer = new DefaultTreeCellRenderer() {        
        @Override
        public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(final JTree tree, Object value,  
            boolean sel,boolean expanded,boolean leaf,int row,boolean hasFocus){
          JLabel label = (JLabel)super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree,value,  
              sel,expanded,leaf,row,hasFocus); 
          if(((DefaultMutableTreeNode)value).isRoot() && ((DefaultMutableTreeNode)value).getChildCount() > 0) {
            TreePath path = tree.getPathForRow(row);
            if(tree.isExpanded(path)) {
              label.setIcon(new IconUIResource(new NodeIcon('-')));
            } else {
              label.setIcon(new IconUIResource(new NodeIcon('+')));
            }
          } else {
            label.setIcon(new IconUIResource(new NodeIcon(' ')));
          }
          return label;  
        }                  
      };
    }    
  }

  @Override
  public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    tree = (JTree) value;
    tree.setCellRenderer(renderer);
    table.setRowHeight(row, tree.getPreferredSize().height);
    return tree;
  }

}

/**
 * Pinched from http://stackoverflow.com/a/7984734/564045
 * @author pstatham
 *
 */
class NodeIcon implements Icon {

  private static final int SIZE = 9;

  private char type;

  public NodeIcon(char type) {
    this.type = type;
  }

  public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
    if(type != ' ') {
      g.setColor(UIManager.getColor("Tree.background"));
      g.fillRect(x, y, SIZE - 1, SIZE - 1);

      g.setColor(UIManager.getColor("Tree.hash").darker());
      g.drawRect(x, y, SIZE - 1, SIZE - 1);

      g.setColor(UIManager.getColor("Tree.foreground"));
      g.drawLine(x + 2, y + SIZE / 2, x + SIZE - 3, y + SIZE / 2);
      if (type == '+') {
        g.drawLine(x + SIZE / 2, y + 2, x + SIZE / 2, y + SIZE - 3);
      }      
    }
  }

  public int getIconWidth() {
    return SIZE;
  }

  public int getIconHeight() {
    return SIZE;
  }
}

/**
 * Wrapper for the background logic
 * http://stackoverflow.com/a/6834797/564045
 * @author pstatham
 *
 * @param <T> return type
 * @param <S> intermediary type (the "shout out")
 */
abstract class LoudCall<T, S> implements Callable<T> {

  private PropertyChangeSupport pcs;
  private S shout;

  public LoudCall() {
    pcs = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
  }

  public void shoutOut(S s) {
    pcs.firePropertyChange("shoutOut", this.shout, this.shout = s);
  }

  public void addListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
    pcs.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
  }

  public void removeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
    pcs.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
  }

  @Override
  public abstract T call() throws Exception;

}

/**
 * Wrapper for the GUI listener.
 * http://stackoverflow.com/a/6834797/564045
 * @author pstatham
 * 
 * @param <T> return type
 * @param <S> intermediary type (the "shout out" to listen for)
 */
abstract class ListenerTask<T, S> extends SwingWorker<T, S> implements PropertyChangeListener {

  private LoudCall<T, S> aMethod;

  public ListenerTask(LoudCall<T, S> aMethod) {
    this.aMethod = aMethod;
  }

  @Override
  protected T doInBackground() throws Exception {
    aMethod.addListener(this);
    return aMethod.call();
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  @Override
  public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
    if("shoutOut".equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
      publish((S)evt.getNewValue());
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected abstract void process(List<S> chunks);
}
```

Comment: from another angle ---> please whats goal, reason or expectation, because fireTableDataChanged() can to reseting everything  for XxxTableCellRenderer (never, don't do that inside Listener, Renderer haven't be set, used, initlaized, changed this way), sure for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnable, compilable with harcoded value for JTable/JTree from local variable

Comment: fireXxxXxx is only for method implemented in models API, and can't be called from outside

Comment: I have an SSCCE but it won't produce a StackOverflow (I developed the concept first which worked and then tried to implement it in to the real code), from my googling I understand that fireXXXX is only for the Models API, but if that's the case what is the best method to (in the above example) to update (a) the JTree (b) the JTable so that they are re-drawn?

Comment: 1. I developed the concept - remove everything about JComponents, Renderer, model its notifier from code posted here, 2. (a) the JTree (b) the JTable so that they are re-drawn? no idea about goal, direction from-to, guessing that there is "something" between JTree and JTable,

Answer (score 0):

It seems that EVERY DefaultTableModel.fire...() method also causes a ListSelectionEvent. Imagine the case that your model is updated after, for example, deleting some previously selected. In that case, the list selection must be recomputed, hence the new ListSelectionEvent. I guess JDK just always recomputes list selection after TableModel.fire...().

Also see [this](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6448158) bug report for JDK.
I was hoping at least for fireTableCellUpdated() it's not happening, but it is.

What you can do is using a flag as described above or filter out these events based on the observation that the first event is a selection 'clear' event (selected rows is empty) and the next event has the same selection as before.
Below the code for the single-selection case:

```
int prevSel = -1;
...
public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent lse) {

   if(lse.getValueIsAdjusting() || getSelectedRows().length==0 || getSelectedRows()[0]==prevSel ) 
     return;
   prevSel = getSelectedRows()[0];

   ... your code ...
   fireTableDataChanged();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I didn't really understand your comments, but I managed to get it working by setting a boolean flag

```
public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent lse) {
   if(!lse.getValueIsAdjusting())
      if(!methodCalled) {
        //Logic for expanding/collapsing JTree and adjusting
        //JTable row height
        methodCalled = true;
        fireTableDataChanged();
        methodCalled = false;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: don't call any of the fireXX manually - it's up to the model to notify its listeners. Or the other way round: if manual firing seems to solve a problem, you are doing something wrong elsewhere

Comment: sigh... I'll post the SSCCE later, so that I can be shown the 'proper' way to do it, which was the point of the question in the first place, I'm here to learn